# Thread wont start on Java

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code should produce a regular frame with time in it, when the time hit 90 minutes it should display a message. somehow the Thread wont start and the message `Thread is working properly` is never displayed. i have already read [the following](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) Oracle article but couldn't find any solution.

```
public class Core extends JFrame implements Runnable{

private int second;
private int minute;
private JLabel presentor;
private Thread threadObject = new Thread();

public Core(){
    second = 1;
    minute = 0;
    presentor = new JLabel();
    writeLabel();
    add(presentor , BorderLayout.CENTER);
    threadObject.start();
}

public void run(){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thread is working properly");
    try{Thread.sleep(60000);}
    catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    updateTime();
    writeLabel();
    if(minute > 89){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "90 minutes have passed away , take a break!");
        this.getParent().setFocusable(true);
    }
}

public void writeLabel(){
    presentor.setText(minute + ":" + second);
}

public void updateTime(){
    second++;
    if(second < 60)
        return;
    second = 0;
    minute++;

}
```

}

there is also a class with the `Main` method which have the basic frame setting, nothing important there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't specify a `Runnable` argument for your `Thread` (which I assume should be `this` since your Core class implements `Runnable`):

```
private Thread threadObject = new Thread(this);
```

Comment: i was trying the whole time `threadObject.start(this)` guess i have much to learn, thanks for the quick help!

Comment: Glad to help. :) Double-checking the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) helps a lot as well.

Answer (score 1):

TNT's answer is correct, but it's not complete.  Your program has more than one problem.  The next problem you will face is that there's no loop in your run() method.  It will call updateTime() and writeLabel() exactly once, and then the thread will terminate.

The next problem after that, is in your updateTime() method.  It appears as if it's meant to count seconds, but your run() method looks like, if it had a loop, it would only call updateTime() once every minute.  That means it will take 90 HOURS, not 90 minutes before your program pops up the dialogue.

Comment: while i wrote this question i notice that and added it quickly on the source file, i'm sincerely sorry for that